# increasing the count on read

Tags: php

```
$dirname1 = '../counters'; 
$dirN = '../uploads';
$extens = ".txt";
$fh = fopen(".$dirname1/$filename.$extens", "w");



if(fopen(".$dirN/$filename.", "r")) {
     $count_my_page = (".$dirname1/$filename.$extens");
     $hits = file($count_my_page);
     $hits[0] ++;
     $fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
     fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
     fclose($fp);
     echo $hits[0];
}
```

each time i open the file, the count should be updated.... but it happens only for the first time.....

Answer (score 1):

Think it might be to do with the increment operator (++), try this:

```
$hits = file($count_my_page);
$nHits = ((int) $hits[0]) + 1;
$fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
fputs($fp , $nHits . "");
fclose($fp);
echo $nHits;
```

Comment: This works, but while refreshing the page.... not on clicking or reading the file.....

Comment: @theband - I don't understand, could you please elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: if i refresh the page where the link is there, it increase the count... not on reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

As count you mean the $count_my_page var ? It is declared inside the if scope, so every loop it is created as a new one.
try declare it outside.

Comment: $count_my_page is a file name, it's a first line within if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is that all in the same file? If so, your first fopen with "w" mode will truncate the file before you read it.

Comment: I mean the fopen() on line 4. It seems to be before any reading?